# How do I use the speaker from my monitor in ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: sound, multiple-monitors, hdmi, soundcard, speakers

The speaker from my Philips monitor doesn't show in the devices availiable for selection, but the monitor is connected to my Ubuntu PC through the HDMI cable. The image works, the sound is not recognized